# How to lock threads dynamically and avoid race condition

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, threadpool

I'm trying to lock threads dynamically, but no matter what I try, there's always some sort of racecondition happening, it seems to be caused by multiple threads started the tasks simultaneously, but I haven't been able to find a good answer to this.

Here is an example:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Example
{
public static readonly Object padLock = new Object();
public readonly static ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> locks = new 
ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
public static List<string> processes = new List<string>();

public static void Main()
{
  //Add random list of processes (just testing with one for now)
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
     processes.Add("random" + i.ToString()); 
  }

  while (true)
  {
     foreach (var process in processes )
     {
        var currentProc = process ;
        lock (padLock)
        {
           if (!locks.ContainsKey(currentProc))
           {
              System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
              {
                 if (!locks.ContainsKey(currentProc))
                 {
                    var lockObject = locks.GetOrAdd(currentProc, new object());
                    lock (lockObject)
                    { 
                       Console.WriteLine("Currently Executing " + currentProc); 
                       Console.WriteLine("Ended Executing " + currentProc);
                       ((IDictionary)locks).Remove(currentProc);
                    }
                 }
              });
           }
        }
       // Thread.Sleep(0);
     }
  }

  Console.ReadLine();
 }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Started 1

Finished 1

Started 1

Finished 1

Started 1

Finished 1
```

but sometimes getting:

```
Started 1

Started 1

Finished 1
```

That is not desired, the dynamic lock should lock it and execute it just once

Comment: hrmm `Started` is not represented in your code, just saying

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish OP? This is a pretty unusual pattern if all you want to do is ensure that each object is processed only once.

Comment: @TheGeneral Started is currently executing

Comment: @JohnWu how would you do it?

Comment: We don't know what you're trying to do. What is the purpose of this?

Comment: MineR each thread should only run once at a time by key, if a thread has a key called thread1 for example, another instance with that key should run

Comment: Note that you actually are only doing one "process" at a time. They merely appear out of order because you're spamming Console.WriteLine and some messages appear out of order.

Comment: @user3044096 - What's the point of `lock (lockObject)`? And, frankly, why `lock (padLock)` (that's completely unnecessary)?

Comment: @user3044096 That wasn't a rhetorical question sir; I don't know your requirements, and it is problematic to infer requirements from broken code, so I asked you what you're trying to do. But I've written an answer assuming my guess was correct, which was "ensure that each object is processed only once." Please comment back if there is more to it.

Comment: @user3044096 I was just trying to see if that stopped them from executing multiple times, I mean each key AKA process should only executed once by iteration

Comment: @user3044096 - Seeing if what was executed multiple times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### This is a common problem

I read your requirements as "Obtain a list of processes, then do something to each of them only once, using multiple threads."

For the purposes of my examples, assume `Foo(process)` does the unit of work that must be done only once.

This is a very common need and there are several patterns.

### Parallel.ForEach

This technique can use a different thread for each iteration of the loop, which will execute concurrently.

```
Parallel.ForEach(processes, process => Foo(process));
```

Yes; it's one line of code.

### async Tasks

This technique is appropriate if `Foo()` is async. It simply schedules a task for all of the processes then awaits them, and lets the SynchronizationContext sort it out.

```
var tasks = processes.Select( p => Foo(process) );
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

### Producer/Consumer

This uses the [producer-consumer pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728068.aspx), which is the traditional way for one thread to add to a queue and another to take from it. By removing an item from the queue, it is effectively "locked" so that other threads don't try to work on it.

```
BlockingCollection<string>() queue = new BlockingCollection<string>();

void SetUpQueue()
{
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) queue.Add(i.ToString());
    queue.CompleteAdding();
}

void Worker()
{
    while (queue.Count > 0 || !queue.IsAddingCompleted)
    {
        var item = queue.Take();
        Foo(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: The Parallel.ForEach seems to give the right result, I just can't understand why this work even when this is inside a while loop, could you please elaborate a little on that part?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Which example are you having trouble with?

Comment: I mean, Parallel.ForEach seems to work, but what I don't understand is why it doesn't start the same thread twice even if it's inside a while loop

Comment: The [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Parallel.cs) is very complicated, but it appears to store the list as an array, creates a series of "workers" (depending on the max degree of parallelism and the number of cores in the CPU), and then each worker grabs items from the array and works on it. It's actually possible for threads to be re-used if there are too many elements in the list, but that is expected.

Comment: Thanks @JohnWu your input is really appreciated, but I feel that MineR is more alligned to what I want to accomplish, Parallel.Foreach is surely something woth to look into, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although I have no idea what you're trying to do, the behavior you're seeing is because you're spamming Console.WriteLine from multiple threads, they are being printed out of order. I validated that by attaching a timestamp to the Console.WriteLine:

```
public class Example
{
  public static readonly Object padLock = new Object();
  public readonly static ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> locks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>(); 
  public static List<string> processes = new List<string>(); 

  [ThreadStatic]
  private static bool flag = false;

 public static void Main()
 {
  //Add random list of processes (just testing with one for now)
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
     processes.Add(i.ToString());
  }

  while (true)
  {
     foreach (var process in processes)
     {
        var currentProc = process; 

        if (!locks.ContainsKey(currentProc))
        {
           var lockObject = locks.GetOrAdd(currentProc, new object());
           Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
               lock (lockObject)
               {
                  if (flag) throw new Exception();
                  flag = true;
                  Console.WriteLine("Currently Executing " + currentProc);
                  Thread.Sleep(0); // You can siimulate work here
                  Console.WriteLine("Ended Executing " + currentProc);
                  flag = false;
                  ((IDictionary)locks).Remove(currentProc);
               }
            });
        }
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Which runs as:

```
....
Ended Executing 1 4025734
Currently Executing 1 4026419
Ended Executing 1 4028737
Currently Executing 1 4029565
Ended Executing 1 4030472
Currently Executing 1 4031643
Currently Executing 1 3659670
Ended Executing 1 4032900
Currently Executing 1 4033582
Ended Executing 1 4034318
Ended Executing 1 4032786
Currently Executing 1 4038042
Ended Executing 1 4042484
Currently Executing 1 4044967
Currently Executing 1 4007282
...
```

Comment: this is a helpful answer, but this is not accurate, I attached the ticks as you stated and Yes, they are out of order, but if you copy and paste you will notice that there are still occurrences

Comment: I added a flag to the code above which will throw an exception if the two events ever appear out of order, and no exception is thrown.

Comment: I ran your code in my local and it threw an exception inmediatly @MineR

Comment: This is interesting though, I would like to know why this doesn't work @MineR

Comment: Yes, if you put the lock in the location as per your edit, it will definitely not enforce one thing to be run at once. You're removing the lock inside the thread ((IDictionary) locks).Remove(currentProc);, so you'd definitely get duplicates through.

Comment: It's possible with the code you've got, which must vary from mine. The above code will actually do nothing because an item is added to the dictionary, and then a check is done to see if the item is in the dictionary, and it always will be, and nothing is done.

Comment: I'm going to edit with the code that I'm actually running and it's working fine